# ModRewrite breaking styles and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I'm very unfamiliar with htaccess, so I have no clue how to tackle this weird issue.

I have a domain connected to a different server by setting the nameservers. Then I use htaccess and ModRewrite to link paths to subfolders on my server, using an existing script like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/t/domainfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /t/domainfolder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ t/domainfolder/index.php [L]
```

This works perfectly, but I'd also like (dynamic) non-existing directories to work, like `domain.com/user/username`. I figured I could do that by adding the following line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/t/domainfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /t/domainfolder/app/index.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /t/domainfolder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ t/domainfolder/index.php [L]
```

This does work, but all styles break and only plain HTML is visible. The console outputs the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

The error points to the `<` of the doctype on the top of the page, so it looks like it is incorrectly parsing the HTML or something. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
my non-working addition seems to break my other domains pointing to this server as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed you break the RewriteCond and RewriteRule  pair, add all these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/t/domainfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /t/domainfolder/app/index.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I added this in place of all my lines, not sure if that's what you meant. This however breaks the main domain and still gives the weird error on the dynamic sub paths... Could it be caused by the server configuration perhaps?

Comment: I got the main domain working again, thanks! All that remains now is that weird issue...

Comment: It's the paths! I need to use relative paths to make it work :) I'll mark your answer as the correct one though, for fixing my modrewrite problem. Seems I had to 2 issues causing trouble.